# Counting Iterations

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am given a question of such:

How many floating point multiplications are performed when each of the following code fragments is executed? Express your answer in terms of n, where n >= 10.

for (i=0;i<8;i++)

```
  for (j=i+1;j<n;j++)

      a[i][j] = a[i][j]*0.125;
```

I am stuck on this question and do not know where to start from. Any ideas?

Comment: The inner loop runs $n-i-1$ times, for each $i$ from $0$ to $7$. Sum over $i$.

Comment: Ok thanks what about the outer loop? And do we just add them to get the  total?

Answer (score 1):

The total number of multiplies is

$$\sum_{i=0}^7 (n-i-1),$$
which you might find it convenient to break up as

$$\sum_{i=0}^7 (n-1) \,- \,\sum_{i=0}^7 i.$$

Comment: Oh ok so that's the final answer but did you consider that n>=10? You didn't forget about that right? Just wanted to clarify.

Comment: Also, for this for(I=0;I<n*n;i++) for(j=0;j<=i;j++) a[i][j]=a[i][j]*0.125;  I got the total of 1/2(n^2+1)(n^2+2) . Is that correct?

Comment: For your first question, yes. If $n\le 7$ you'd have to be more careful (do you see why?).  For the second question I get $$\sum_{i=0}^{n^2-1} (i+1) =  n^2(n^2-1)/2 +n^2 = n^2(n^2+1)/2.$$

Comment: Ok and what about this: for (I=1;I<n;i=I+2) for (j=0;j<=I;j++) a[i][j]=a[i][j]*0.125; I am having trouble figuring this out.

Comment: You might try writing $i=2k+1$, so that $k$ runs from $0$ to $\lfloor n/2\rfloor$ (do you see why?) and the number of iterations in the inner loop is $2k+2$ instead of $i+1$.

Comment: Ok so what's the final answer for this. Can you show me using sum notation. That really helps me.

Comment: Write $m=\lfloor n/2\rfloor$.  Then the sum is $$\sum_{k=0}^m (2k+2) = 2\sum_{k=1}^{m+1} k = (m+1)(m+2).$$

Comment: Ok thanks man. I probably have more questions but for now it's good.

Comment: Great.  Feel free to upvote my answer then!

Comment: Ok another question, in each of the following algorithms, the function baseFun is to be considered the basic operation. The size of the input is given by n and you many assume that no array index exceptions arise. Perform a worst case analysis for each algorithm.  for(I=0;I<n;I++) for (j = 0;j<=n;j++) for (k=I;k<=i*i;k++) if (condition(I,j,k)) b[i][k] = baseFun(b[i][j]); else b[i][k]=b[j][k]; so I am guessing the first line executes only n times but the rest of the lines I am not sure.

Comment: Ok I tried doing it and got this as my final answer. 1/3n^5+7/3n^4+20/3n^3+14/3n^2. Is that correct?